# Analytics hasn't updated keywords the last week, what could be the problem?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics

The Keywords section under "Sources" in my GA account hardly updated at all.
I KNOW I had more than 2 searches for a keyword, but GA doesn't show these?

I have a GA account and I have a tracking code like this on my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function fnx(that, outbound) {
    try {
        var pageTracker=_gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxx-1");
         pageTracker._trackPageview(outbound);
         setTimeout('document.location = "' + that.href + '"', 100)
        }catch(err){}
      }
  </script>
```

First part is the GA tracking code.
The second is just to be able to track clicks on some certain banners on the site.

Anybody familiar with this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you (or whoever did the search) using an ad blocker? They often block tracking scripts like GA.

Also make sure it's not anything silly like the code not actually being on the page you go to, or you've told GA to ignore your IP address, or you have JS disabled. Make sure you are checking in the correct date range and checking every search term in the list.

Perhaps try removing that custom code temporarily to check that it's not the cause of the problem.

I don't know if GA does actually log every search term. For example it may not log long exact queries (in quotes) and it may not log things like `site:` queries.